Duende Identity server PostLogoutRedirectUri is always empty for .NET MAUI iOS client
I am using Duende IdentityServer 7 as my identity provider and.NET MAUI for my iOS application. I have registered client with identity server with both RedirectUri and PostLogoutRedirectUri. Login flow is working fine but logout flow is not. In IdentityServer, PostLogoutRedirectUri is coming empty and as a result, it is not redirecting to the app and stuck with the browser view.
I have my .NET MAUI client as
private static void AddService(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<WebAuthenticatorBrowser>();

    services.AddTransient<OidcClient>(sp =>
        new OidcClient(new OidcClientOptions
        {
            Authority = "https://identity-url"
            ClientId = "CLientId",
            RedirectUri = "myapp://",
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = "myapp://",
            Scope = "scope1 scope2,
            Browser = sp.GetRequiredService<WebAuthenticatorBrowser>(),
            DisablePushedAuthorization = false
        })
    );
}

On click of Logout, it then calls OidcClient like:
LogoutRequest logoutRequest = new LogoutRequest();
LogoutResult? logoutResult = await OidcClient.LogoutAsync(logoutRequest);

I have tried it with this as well without any luck.
LogoutRequest logoutRequest = new LogoutRequest
{
    IdTokenHint = token
};
LogoutResult? logoutResult = await OidcClient.LogoutAsync(logoutRequest);

And my identity server code looks like this.
[SecurityHeaders]
[AllowAnonymous]
public class LoggedOut : PageModel
{
    private readonly IIdentityServerInteractionService _interactionService;

    public LoggedOutViewModel View { get; set; } = new();

    public LoggedOut(IIdentityServerInteractionService interactionService)
    {
        _interactionService = interactionService;
    }

    public async Task OnGet(string logoutId)
    {
        LogoutRequest logout = await _interactionService.GetLogoutContextAsync(logoutId);

        View = new LoggedOutViewModel
        {
            AutomaticRedirectAfterSignOut = LogoutOptions.AutomaticRedirectAfterSignOut,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = logout.PostLogoutRedirectUri ?? "",
            ClientName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(logout.ClientName) ? logout.ClientId ?? string.Empty : logout.ClientName,
            SignOutIframeUrl = logout.SignOutIFrameUrl ?? string.Empty,
        };
    }
}

Here PostLogoutRedirectUri is always empty for MAUI app. I can see logoutId being passed to the method. Other WebClients using same Identity Server work as expected.
Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Solved the issue. I was passing access token instead of identity token.

LogoutRequest logoutRequest = new LogoutRequest
{
    IdTokenHint = token // has to be identity token
};
LogoutResult? logoutResult = await OidcClient.LogoutAsync(logoutRequest);


